# Bot didn't send DM when voted on Top.gg

Tags: python, discord.py

I was trying to figure out how to fix the problem. It didn't print anything nor sent a DM.

Code:

```
async def on_dbl_vote(self, ctx, data):
        print("Received an upvote:")
        await ctx.author.send(f"hey {ctx.author.name}, thanks for voting!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you should be doing `user.send` while `ctx.author.send` would just send it to the author of a message which is not specified

Comment: Ok, let me try it

Comment: Hey there. is this also the same method for checking if someone has voted for a server?